# Wordpress posts fetch error using json

Tags: angularjs, json, wordpress, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic & angular.js to create a cross platform application and I am not being able to fetch all the post from word-press using json offset parameter, it fetched only 10 post by default I am suing infinite scroll of Ionic and Angular.js functions to do so but not being able to fetch all the posts

```
#controller.js

angular.module('starter')

.controller('MenuCtrl', function MenuCtrl($http, $scope, $sce, $ionicScrollDelegate){

    $scope.categories = [];



    $http.get("http://bijay.sahikura.com/api/get_category_index/")
        .then(function(returnedData){

            $scope.categories = returnedData.data.categories;
            $scope.categories.forEach(
                function(element, index, array){ 
                    element.title = $sce.trustAsHtml(element.title);
                });

            console.log(returnedData);
        },

        function(err){
            console.log(err);
        });

    $scope.doRefresh = function(){
        $scope.recent_posts = [];
        $http.get("http://bijay.sahikura.com/api/get_posts/")
            .then(function(data){
                console.log(data); 
                $scope.recent_posts = data.data.posts; 

                $scope.recent_posts.forEach(
                    function(element, index, array){
                        element.excerpt = element.excerpt.substr(0,100);
                        element.excerpt = element.excerpt + "   ...   पुरा   पढ्नुहाेस"; 
                        element.excerpt = $sce.trustAsHtml(element.excerpt);
                        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
                });
            });

    };

    $scope.recent_posts = [];
    $http.get("http://bijay.sahikura.com/api/get_posts/")
        .then(function(data){
            console.log(data); 
            $scope.recent_posts = data.data.posts; 

            $scope.recent_posts.forEach(
                function(element, index, array){
                    element.excerpt = element.excerpt.substr(0,100);
                    element.excerpt = element.excerpt + "   ...   पुरा पढ्नुहाेस"; 
                    element.excerpt = $sce.trustAsHtml(element.excerpt);
            });
        });

        **$scope.canLoadMore = function()
        {
            return true; 
        };
        $scope.count=0;
        $scope.loadMore = function(){
            console.log($scope.count++);

            $http.get("http://bijay.sahikura.com/api/get_posts/?offset= "+$scope.offset)
                .then(function(data){
                        var newPosts = data.data.posts;
                        $scope.count_total = data.data.count_total;

                        newPosts.forEach(
                            function(element, index, array){
                                element.excerpt = element.excerpt.substr(0,100);
                                element.excerpt = element.excerpt + "   ...   पुरा पढ्नुहाेस"; 
                                element.excerpt = $sce.trustAsHtml(element.excerpt);

                        })

                        $scope.recent_posts.push.apply($scope.recent_posts, newPosts);
                        $scope.$broadcast('scroll.infiniteScrollComplete');             


                            $scope.offset = +10 ;                   
                        })                                                                                                                      

        };**



        $scope.searchTextChanged = function(){
            $ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle('mainScroll').scrollTop(true);
        };


    })


.controller('PostCtrl', function() {
    //alert("hello!");
    })

menucontent.html

<ion-view>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-assertive">

        <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
            <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"> 
            </button> 
        </ion-nav-buttons> 
        <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
            <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-heart">
            </button> 
        </ion-nav-buttons> 
    </ion-nav-bar> 
        <ion-header-bar class="bar bar-assertive"> 
            <div class="title"> <center>Hello</center> </div> 
        </ion-header-bar>

        <div class="bar bar-subheader item-input-inset"> 
            <label class="item-input-inset"> 
                <i class="icon ion-ios-search placeholder-icon"> </i> 
                <input type="search" placeholder="Search..." ng-model="searchText" ng-change="searchTextChanged()"/>
            </label> 
        </div>
        <ion-content class="has-subheader" delegate-handle="mainScroll"> 
            <ion-refresher
                pulling-text="Update ..."
                on-refresh="doRefresh()">
            </ion-refresher> 

            <ion-list can-swipe="true">
                <ion-item class="item item-thumbnail-left item-text-wrap item-icon-right" ng-repeat="post in recent_posts | filter: {title: searchText}">
                        <img src="{{post.thumbnail}}"/> 
                        <h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
                        <p ng-bind-html="post.excerpt"> </P>
                    <ion-option-button class="button-dark"> 
                        <i class="icon ion-heart"> </i> 
                    </ion-option-button>
                </ion-item>
            </ion-list> 
                <ion-infinite-scroll ng-if="canLoadMore()" on-infinite="loadMore()">
                </ion-infinite-scroll>
        </ion-content> 
</ion-view>
```